# Avoiding Duplicate Boilerplate Code in WCF Service

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, wcf, web-services

I'm responsible for maintaining a web service project in c#.  I have one service class with a bunch of methods that look a lot like this:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "v1/Login", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public string Login()
    {
        try
        {
            JObject incomingRequestJson = retrieveJson();
            JObject returningJson = new JObject();

            string accountId = incomingRequestJson.SelectToken("accountId", true).ToString();
            string username = incomingRequestJson.SelectToken("userName", true).ToString();
            string password = incomingRequestJson.SelectToken("password", true).ToString();

            LoginResult result = readerBLL.Login(accountId, username, password);
            returningJson.Add(new JProperty("userSessionId", result.userSessionId));
            returningJson.Add(new JProperty("friendlyUserName", result.friendlyUserName));

            return returningJson.ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new WebFaultException<string>(ex.Message.ToString(), HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
    }
```

Note that `retrieveJson()` grabs a JSON string from the `HttpContext` and runs `JObject.Parse()` on it.
Note also that the consumer of this service is a Flex app, so I do need the WebFaultException business with the "OK" response code (The networking component in Flex treats connection timeouts and all HTTP error codes exactly the same - no further data other than

I don't like the way I have the `try-catch` block repeated in every method, so I tried making the following method:

```
private object invokeBusinessLogic(Func<JObject, object> f)
    {
        try
        {
            return f(retrieveJson());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            WebFaultException<string> wfe = new WebFaultException<string>(ex.Message.ToString(), HttpStatusCode.OK);
            throw wfe;
        }
    }
```

Then my service methods can look like this:

```
public object Login()
{
    LoginResult result = (LoginResult) invokeBusinessLogic(readerBLL.Login);
    returningJson.Add(new JProperty("userSessionId", result.userSessionId));
    returningJson.Add(new JProperty("friendlyUserName", result.friendlyUserName));

    return returningJson.ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None);
}
```

However, this has the problem that the use of JSON to carry the request data gets exposed to the business layer.  Is there a better way to avoid the duplicate `try-catch` blocks than this `invokeBusinessLogic` idea?

Comment: Why are you parsing and creating the JSONs instead of using serialization? I think that would simplify your code quite a lot.

Comment: Historical reasons.  I'd love to change it, but then the clients of this service would need to be updated.  That's something for version 2 of this service.

Comment: Why would that affect the clients? You could still serialize to the same JSON.

Comment: Oh, perhaps I misunderstood you.  I thought doing serialization would mean function signatures like `public LoginResult Login()` in the service layer -- and that would break my clients.  The current code actually sends an escaped string rather than a real JSON string :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure why your change all of a sudden would expose data to the business layer when it didn't before.

If you have a pattern of methods which look like this:

```
public string MyServiceCall()
{
    try
    {
        JObject incomingRequestJson = retrieveJson();
        JObject returningJson = new JObject();

        // do stuff

        return returningJson.ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new WebFaultException<string>(ex.Message.ToString(), HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
}
```

Then you can simply add a helper method to your service implementation:

```
private string ProcessServiceCall(Func<JObject, JObject> processor)
{
    try
    {
        JObject incomingRequestJson = retrieveJson();
        JObject returningJson = processor(incomingRequestJson);

        return returningJson.ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new WebFaultException<string>(ex.Message.ToString(), HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
}
```

and your service call then becomes:

```
public string MyServiceCall()
{
    ProcessServiceCall(incomingRequestJson => {

        string accountId = incomingRequestJson.SelectToken("accountId", true).ToString();
        string username = incomingRequestJson.SelectToken("userName", true).ToString();
        string password = incomingRequestJson.SelectToken("password", true).ToString();

        JObject result = new JObject();

        LoginResult result = readerBLL.Login(accountId, username, password);
        result.Add(new JProperty("userSessionId", result.userSessionId));
        result.Add(new JProperty("friendlyUserName", result.friendlyUserName));

        return result;
    }
}
```

This should be a simple refactoring on your service class and not expose any more json to the business logic than before.

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect.  I hadn't thought of doing an anonymous function to pass to ProcessServiceCall.

Comment: Maybe reuse source code (common logic, implementation) for WebAPI, WCF Service (JSON), WCF Service (SOAP-XML)? _IMHO, better samples for minimize learning curve are real 

applications with full source code and good patterns_